# Finding the current in the falling circular metal plate at any time $T$. (Magnetic field and Electricity)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction

A circular metal plate starts falling from rest, straight vertically in region of uniform magnetic field of intensity $B$. The magnetic field is parallel to the surface of earth and to the plane of the plate. The acceleration of free fall is $g$. The plate has mass $m$ and its thickness $d$, is much smaller than its radius $R$. (neglect the edge effects)

Calculate the current in the plate at any time t. In terms of B,R,g,m,d.

I need help in calculating Emf and we are not given resistance of the plate also. So , I want to know is there a way  to solve this problem. I tried Motional Emf which will be induced but without given the resistance of plate I don't see a way to find current. Am I missing some concept in that case please explain.

[image: Rear view of circular metal plate falling]

Comment: I'm wondering more how to eliminate Q in favour of $\epsilon_0$ surely to do this I need to use gauss law?